# how do i build sensors in untiy 2d for machine learning?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, machine-learning

I do not have any code because I'm stuck. I'm trying to build an algorithm that teaches a car to go around a track, but I need a way for the car to see so I'm trying to build sensors. Everyone suggests using the position of a wall minus the sensor's position, but this does not work because it only sees the center of the wall. I need to make it so that the sensor tells me the distance between the part of the wall it is pointed at and the sensor itself. How can I do this or what is an alternative for the AI to see.

Comment: If you're stuck you need to [find a simpler problem](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/). Try hard-coding the distance then putting your car at that distance. Get that working before playing with sensors.

Answer (score 0):

Use raycasting. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

The following code should give you the distance as a float:

```
float distance = 0.0f;
if (Physics.Raycast(sensor.transform.position, 
sensor.transform.forward, out hit, sensorRange, 
layerMask))
{
    distance = Vector3.Distance(sensor.transform.position,
                                hit.point);
}
```

I cannot try it right now because I'm not in a computer with Unity, but the idea is that.
Use the sensor as a GameObject parented to the car. Also, remember to aim the sensor to the direction you want, rotating it.